# Effective comment annotation in Scala Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin

I was wondering if anyone can explain where and how comment documentation in Scala is applicable - in particular, the Eclipse plugin. For example, is there a way to comment a procedure, that might later show as a help-hint while using Eclipse? I'm not entirely sure how to get these Javadoc like effects when using Scala Eclipse. I've checked the various FAQs for the plugin, it's possibly not supported but I can't find an explanation either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScalaDoc on hover/completion is not yet integrated in the Scala IDE.

The good news is that this feature is currently under development and we plan to have intial support for it in the coming months. A Pull Request for adding ScalaDoc in support in the Scala Presentation Compiler has been [recently merged](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2075).

A Pull Request on the [Scala IDE project](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide) will follow. You can track progress on this feature [here](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000210)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Scaladoc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html), but it isn't supported [completely yet](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&object_scope=60&q=scaladoc+).